# How can I fix letterboxing / stretching?

Tags: resolution, hdmi, tv

I'm using a Samsung syncmaster 2032mw TV as a pc monitor, it works perfectly fine over vga but I want sound and there's no space / sockets for the speakers I have. I opted to use HDMI which is perfect as it's a TV so has speakers, but it seems the TV only accept 16:9 inputs... Even though it's a 16:10 TV, so I either get letterboxing or stretching when I play around with settings, even when I set it to the native 1680x1050 resolution it literally cuts off the top and bottom which would fit the screen perfectly.

What I was thinking of doing was using the zoom setting which fits the input to the screen, cutting off the sides, and using a 16:9 resolution with a height of 1050 and then applying black bars either side of the input so then ultimately it would fit perfectly and I'd get my desired speakers. 
The (1050/9)x16=1866.66 which I'd translate to a resolution of 1866x1050. (1866-1680)/2=93, so either side there would be about 93 pixels of unused resolution that would be cut off by the zoom function of the TV, I just want to know whether it's at all possible to do anything like this in Windows....

I have an AMD CPU/GPU. 
I'm 100% sure the TV won't accept a native 16:10 resolution due to its firmware configuration, and sure it's not a problem with the HDMI Cable/pc.

Comment: So why don’t you just try what you proposed? Stuff like that can only be set in the control panel that comes with your graphics driver. Also, why not use DVI?

Comment: I had a look in the control panel,  I didn't see an option to "create custom resolution and then cut off a specific amount of both sides"